# How to set a mail Subject in UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, uiactivityviewcontroller, subject

I want to set subject for email sharing in `UIActivityViewController` and also want to share in Twitter. I know in Twitter if we want to share — we need compress text to 140 chars. I checked many SO solutions, but nothing is working.

Is this issue fixed in latest iOS releases? Any other "working solutions"?

Comment: No it dint. Just check my comment below and let me know if i miss the right way. thank you

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It seems as though emreoktem's solution—sending `setValue:forKey:` to the `UIActivityViewController`—is undocumented.

On iOS 7 and later, you can implement the `activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:` method in an object conforming to the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol to do this in a way that is documented.

Comment: Yes, `activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:` is the correct solution. Strangely the iOS Mail app uses the subject correctly **but Google Inbox** uses the message for the subject as well (not the subject supplied via `subjectForActivityType`)

Comment: @LeslieGodwin Did you found any solution for sharing via gmail?

Comment: @TimCamber Though I have tried above way it is still showing problem via sharing in gmail. Please help to resolve

Comment: @jalakpatel I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you sharing something to the Google Gmail app? In that case, it may not be `UIActivityViewController`'s fault that the Gmail app is not picking up `activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:`.

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer.  I've added an answer with a concrete class for Swift 3+ that I found very useful.

Answer (score 97):

Check below code for the email for setting up your email subject:

```
UIActivityViewController* avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Your String to share"]
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[avc setValue:@"Your email Subject" forKey:@"subject"];

avc.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    // ...
};
```

Here the line

> [avc setValue:@"Your email Subject" forKey:@"subject"];

Makes the subject as "Your email Subject" if user picks email option in the UIActivityViewController.

I hope it helps...

Comment: [activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
            if([activityType isEqualToString: UIActivityTypeMail]){
                NSLog(@"Mail type selected");
                [activityVC setValue:@"Share!" forKey:@"subject"];
            }
            
            
        }]; Its not working emreoktem!

Comment: @Meenu You should set the subject *before* the completion handler.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in iOS8, is there another way of doing this?

Comment: is There any way to set recipient also??

Comment: This and the activityViewController:subjectForActivityType: are annoyingly setting email subject and navigation bar title to the same string. It would be nice to have a official and documented way to do that.

Comment: but email subject is not showing when I am opening gmail application.I am getting Body content in Gmail Subject section

Comment: It's undocumented and not preferred.

Answer (score 33):

Here's a concrete solution for **Swift 3.0+** based on the accepted answer.  Note that, like the accepted answer, this is known to work only on the iOS Mail app and not necessarily other apps.

## Implementation:

```
class MessageWithSubject: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {

    let subject:String
    let message:String

    init(subject: String, message: String) {
        self.subject = subject
        self.message = message

        super.init()
    }

    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return message
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
        return message
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController,
                                subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> String {
        return subject
    }
}
```

## Usage:

Here's an example of usage.  Note that it works well to use this as the first item in the activityItems array, and include any additional items to follow:

```
let message = MessageWithSubject(subject: "Here is the subject", message: "An introductory message")
let itemsToShare:[Any] = [ message, image, url, etc ]

let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: itemsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
```

Comment: The following solution doesn't work for `Gmail` app but only for `ios Mail app`.
On Gmail the body is being shown the same as a message subject

Comment: That's true Gal, just like the accepted answer on which it is based.  I added a comment to make that more explicit.

Comment: Class name should start with capital letter.

Comment: syntax for Swift 5 is a tiny bit different with optionals etc. but this is great thanks.

Answer (score 19):

For Swift 2.0+ & ios 8.0+

```
let title = "Title of the post"
let content = "Content of the post"
let objectsToShare = [title, content]

let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)      
activityVC.setValue(title, forKey: "Subject")
self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: does this work for sharing a link to a website?  like [title, content, link]

or does the URL has to be part of the content itself and let the email client parse it and make it clickable?

Comment: Per the accepted answer, this is undocumented and unreliable.

Comment: One suggestion is to leave the 'title' off the objectsToShare, since adding the title in the setValue sets the Subject in the Email already.  Works for me.