# How to set mail subject with UIActivityItemProvider

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using `UIActivityViewController` for sharing information through email. We are able to send email with body, attachments with no problem. But how do we set the subject title for the email.

I notice this question: [How to set a mail Subject in UIActivityViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020288/how-to-set-mail-subject-in-uiactivityviewcontroller-and-also-twitter-sharing-te)
The accepted solution is using `UIActivityItemSource` with this following API [activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIActivityItemSource/activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:). However, our code doesn't conform to `UIActivityItemSource` because we are using `UIActivityItemProvider`.

> **UIActivityItemSource**
>
> You can use this protocol in situations where you want to provide the data from one of your app’s existing objects instead of creating a separate UIActivityItemProvider object.

So the complete question is:

**How do I set the email subject if I am using `UIActivityItemProvider` instead of UIActivityItemSource?**

Comment: Look this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581389/how-do-i-use-uiactivityitemprovider-to-send-an-email-with-attachment-with-uiacti

Comment: This is kind of cool. I didn't know that we can still use UIActivityItemProvider without even explicitly adding it to UIActivityItemProvider. Thanks man. This sounds like the correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define your custom item provider:

```
@interface CustomProvider : UIActivityItemProvider
@end
```

Add to your implementation:

```
@implementation CustomProvider

// Some other code ... -(id)item and etc. 

- (NSString *) activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
               subjectForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
      return @"A dummy Title";
}

@end
```

Notice that `UIActivityItemProvider` will automatically conform to `UIactivityItemSource` protocol. The difference is, you don't have to implement those `@required` API for `UIactivityItemSource` protocol.

Answer (score 5):

Just add this line after you instantiate your UIActivityViewController:

```
[activityController setValue:@"Your email Subject" forKey:@"subject"];
```

I am using it like this:

```
- (void)share {
    NSArray *activityItems;

    NSString *texttoshare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey bro! check this info.\n%@\n%@", self.infoBean.title, self.infoBean.desc];
    UIImage *imagetoshare = imageView.image;//this is your image to share

    if (imagetoshare != nil) {
    activityItems = @[imagetoshare, texttoshare];
    } else {
    activityItems = @[texttoshare];
    }
    NSArray *exTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];


    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = exTypes;


    [activityController setValue:@"Your email Subject" forKey:@"subject"];

    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is one possible answer. However, I don't quite like using undocumented api. I will provide a answer which is a more elegant one based on the comments.

Answer (score 2):

`UIActivityItemProvider` implements the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol. It's right there in the header.

```
@interface UIActivityItemProvider : NSOperation <UIActivityItemSource>
```

so you can simply use the method `- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController subjectForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType` to return the subject in your `UIActivityItemProvider` subclass.