# iOS : customize of activityViewController

Tags: ios, swift

hi I implemented activityViewController and my activityItems is text when I press button this will pop up and I choose mail IMPORTENT : when I choose it my text in the (activityItems) go to the message body but I want it to go in sender message textfield (To :)

how should I implement this???

```
@IBAction func activityView(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let text = "Mahdi.m@email.com"
    let img = UIImage(named: "Buliding")!
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text, img], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop]
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I dont think that you can do it. you can set the body and the subject. but not the email address

Comment: I saw in some app

Comment: if I want to do this for subject what should I do??

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070038/how-to-set-mail-subject-with-uiactivityitemprovider. example code is in Objective-c but there should be others, or its easy to convert