# ios/objective-c: Set email subject in activityviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

According to the accepted answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020288/how-to-set-a-mail-subject-in-uiactivityviewcontroller), the correct, Apple-approved way to set the subject of an email through the activityviewcontroller is to use the following method:

```
activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:
```

Can anyone provide an example of how to use this?

For example, how would I set the subject for an activity view controller named AVC.

```
 UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems: activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

NSString *subject = @"Check this out";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070038/how-to-set-mail-subject-with-uiactivityitemprovider

Comment: The accepted answer does not show how to call it. I do not believe it's a delegate as I included this method and declare the protocol but it does not fire.  The other answer (valueforKey) is undocumented.

Comment: it is a subclassed custom subclassed itemprovider. Check this thread a better more informed solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581389/how-do-i-use-uiactivityitemprovider-to-send-an-email-with-attachment-with-uiacti